# How to fix my code to remove the casting warning?

Tags: kotlin

I have some code similar to this:

```
private val elements: ArrayList<ISomeElement> = ArrayList()
```

...

```
override fun curElements(): Collection<GenericElement> {  
  ...
  return elements as Collection<GenericElement> // squigly underline here, unchecked cast warning

}
```

all `ISomeElement` objects in elements are `GenericElement` objects that implement `ISomeElement`

how could I fix my code to remove this warning? The code works fine, it's just the warning I'm asking about

I can't change the return type of the fun

Comment: What's the relationship between GenericElement and ISomeElement? Show their definition.

Comment: Then there's nothing you can do. You're effectively doing something unsafe, and the compiler can't check that what you're doing is safe. All you can do is suppressing the warning, and pray that the list indeed only contains GenericElement instances. But if it's supposed to contain only GenericElement instances, why don't you declare it as ArrayList<GenericElement>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If `ISomeElement` extends `GenericElement` then you will not get such a warning; you won't even need an explicit cast with the explicit function return type present.
2. If `ISomeElement` does not extend `GenericElement` then there is no safe way to "cast" a `Collection<ISomeElement>` to a `Collection<GenericElement>`.

   You can `map` the elements to a new collection of the desired type:

   ```
   fun curElements(): Collection<GenericElement> {
       return elements.map { it as GenericElement }
   }
   ```

   You can also filter the collection if you know there may be some elements in the collection that do not implement `GenericElement` and you want to silently ignore them:

   ```
   fun curElements(): Collection<GenericElement> {
       return elements.filterIsInstance<GenericElement>()
   }
   ```

   If you are certain that all of the `elements` implement `GenericElement` then you can suppress the warning:

   ```
   fun curElements(): Collection<GenericElement> {
       @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
       return elements as Collection<GenericElement>
   }
   ```

   You can also change the type of `elements` to `ArrayList<GenericElement>` and then cast each `ISomeElement` instance to `GenericElement` as you add them to the collection:

   ```
   elements.add(iSomeElement as GenericElement)
   ```

Comment: `ISomeElement` is an interface, so it can't extend the `GenericElement` class (I moved the comment describing that into the actual original post now)

Comment: I'm lazy so I guess I'll just the suppress warning. What is the scope of the suppression? just the next statement? I figure if my code got changed somehow inadvertently then at least I'd get some kind of runtime exception to tell me I screwed up. As it stands now this is a safe cast, the compiler just doesn't know it.

Comment: although I didn't know about that `filterIsInstance()`, looks like a useful filter

Comment: The scope can be defined as file, fun, or statement. I had it unnecessarily defined at the fun (function) level so I've updated my answer to only suppress it for the return statement.